# Cannot import any pallets to the run time of node template

Tags: substrate-node-template

I have configured the staking pallet in the Substrate node template and tried to add it to the Cargo.toml in Run time
Then it ended up in the following error when building
This happens if I add any pallets to the cargo toml

What should be the fix for this ?

```
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }
pallet-stakingt = { version = "0.0.1", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/staking" }
```

```
error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /home/dev/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.6/src/lib.rs:235:9
      |
  235 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by \
  236 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  237 | |                         For more information see: \
  238 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /home/dev/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.6/src/lib.rs:262:5
      |
  262 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
      |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
```

```
features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-executive/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "pallet-aura/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-grandpa/std",
    "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std",
    "pallet-sudo/std",
    "pallet-template/std",
    "pallet-staking/std",
    "pallet-dct/std",
    "pallet-uniques/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
    "sp-api/std",
    "sp-block-builder/std",
    "sp-consensus-aura/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-inherents/std",
    "sp-offchain/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-session/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-transaction-pool/std",
    "sp-version/std",
]
```

Comment: I used to get this error when adding custom RPCs to my node. The error has nothing to do with your pallet, it might be an issue regarding your pallet configuration for the node or the runtime. In my case the issue was that I was missing some configuration for the node/rpc.rs file and therefore this error was appearing, even thought its not related

Comment: Thank you yes that was the issue

Comment: @ox12 if you resolved the issue, can you write a self-answer and mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

If the changes you showed above are the only changes you made, you did not add your pallet to your runtime correctly.

Take a look at this tutorial showing you how to add a pallet to your runtime: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/add-a-pallet/

Beyond adding the pallet to your runtime like:

```
pallet-nicks = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
```

You need to also properly enable the `std` feature flag:

```
[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    ...
    'pallet-aura/std',
    'pallet-balances/std',
    'pallet-nicks/std',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the wasm target support to the rust toolchain as such:

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

Comment: Already did  

dev@dev:~/Desktop/project/giant-teller-poa$ rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date

Comment: In addition how that this can be different from other implementations since STD has been passed and yes I am building in my Linux instance Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

This error may indicate that you are trying to compile the code for the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` platform and at the same time passing the `std` feature.

The `std` feature is supposed to be passed **only** when building for the host platform, i.e. for you laptop or server which likely runs *nix/macOS or Windows.

Is there a chance that that's the case?

Comment: Not likely , there is no relation on those 2 since the legacy projects are working ( v3.0.0 )

Answer (score -1):

This is caused because of `getrandom` library which is a dependency of one of the other crates.
Add this line to the `Cargo.toml` file of the crate *which has this lib as a dependency*:
`getrandom = { version = "0.2", features = ["js"] }`

For example if dependencies look like this:

```
your_crate
  |
lib_a
  |
lib_b
  |
getrandom
```

then you should add this line to `your_crate/Cargo.toml`

Comment: This won't solve the issue, that solution only works if you are indeed using that package, which is not the case. As you can see on the first comment of his question, the issue has nothing to do with that package.

Comment: I had exactly the same error 3 days ago and the solution I've provided worked.Before that I did everything from previous comments here and nothing worked

Answer (score -1):

Okay Im Writing the answer here

The issue was that I haven't followed the dependencies declared order in node template. Once I implement the same on that , it worked

Not sure why I got down voted
Not ethical !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah, so even the order of dependencies declarations in `Cargo.toml`s matters? Could you please share the version of your `toml` that fixed the issue? I'm facing the same problem now...