# How to enable `std` features in pallets?

Tags: runtime, substrate-node-template, wasm, no-std

I'm trying to implement simple PoW for my node. After debugging all other stuff I've encountered the problem where `finality-grandpa` and `storage` do not get compiled because standard library macros are (for some reason) out of scope.

I've checked that `std` features and enabled for all dependencies where they need to be enabled. Also I found [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features-examples.html?highlight=no-std#:%7E:text=full%20standard%20library.-,The%20wasm%2Dbindgen,-package%20defines%20a) information about one of the dependencies. But as it's a non-local (pulled from github) I can't change that functionality.

Please note that I did not modify any of these two pallets (just imported my own, implementing PoW). Before that (on clear substrate-node-template which I use as a base for my project) those built without any problem.

The question is: How do I fix this? Should I enable `std` for these crates somehow?
As far as I know, the node is built into native Rust and WASM, and for WASM it's built in no-std. By why did it build before in this case?

Here is a part of the error message I get:

```
cargo build --release 
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/creestl/programming/blockchain/crain/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/creestl/programming/blockchain/crain/runtime)`
 
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/creestl/programming/blockchain/crain/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-d1d0301f1ce42478/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/creestl/programming/blockchain/crain/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.62.0-nightly (de1bc0008 2022-04-21)
 
 
  --- stderr
     Compiling frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)
     Compiling sp-finality-grandpa v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)
  error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
    --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             alloc::format
             scale_info::prelude::format
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
 
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `std`
    --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `std`
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
 
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `String`
    --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: consider importing one of these items
     |
  42 |     use alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use codec::alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use scale_info::prelude::string::String;
     |
```

And here is a [link](https://github.com/CREESTL/Crain) to the repo with my last changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.
The reason for the bug was that I've included

```
getrandom = {version = "0.2", features= ["js"] }
```

in `Cargo.toml` of one of my crates. And that caused some inner conflicts. After I removed that dependency - everything was OK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

> standard library macros are (for some reason) out of scope.

*TL;DR: you cannont use `std` in runtime development*

As you see on the [node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs) all *runtime* files must not use `std` because they target Wasm, and thus cannot generally use the full `std`, and include:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

Instead of the full library, the general subset of `std` types and traits you likely need are in [`sp_std`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_std/index.html). This includes primitives like `str` and `vec` modules. Of note, it's likely for runtime development [`frame_support::storage::BoundedVec`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html) should be used though, as boundedness is typically critical in runtimes).

Comment: Yes, I know that runtime compiles to WASM in no-std. But here is a short list of operations that caused a bug described in the question:
1) Clone Node Template. Builds successfully  

2) Import sp-consensus-pow. Change some stuff in it.  

3) Build again. Build fails. And the error occurs somewhere in `finalty-grandpa` and `storage` crates because of `std` feature.  

Once again, I did _not_ change anything in those crates (they are the same as in step 1), but they fail to build. Why so?

Comment: An error similar to mine was described [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4333)

Comment: Are you using the recent rust stable version?

Comment: Yes. I've updated to stable 1.60 and nightly 1.62. Also added wasm32-unknown-unknown as a new target

Comment: Sounds silly, but perhaps its as simple as missing feature flags https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2088/34 but I have not reviewed your node linked in the OP to determine for sure

Comment: No, `std` features were the first thing I've checked. They are all in place.